# How can I get tags of a secret in Key vault using event grid?

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-eventgrid

I am writing a PowerShell runbook in Automation Account that handles Key Vault notifications via Event Grid. The goal is firstly email **someone** when the secret is about to expire or has expired. I wanted to use a Tag on the secret called "contact" with an email address of who to email, but the **tags are not included in the Event Grid event schema.**

The second goal was to automatically rotate the password, but we have different sources (on premise AD, AAD, app registrations, etc.) where the password would need to be changed, so again I was hoping to rely on Tags to identity the type of secret so the auto-rotate logic could function.

**Question: Assuming Tags are the best way to handle this, is there a way to include tags in the event schema? Otherwise, is there an alternative to using Tags?**

Answer (score 0):

The Event Grid event schema for Key Vault notifications does not include tags.

> The requirement is email **someone** when the secret is about to
> expire or has expired....

As there is **no tags option available** you can **still achieve** your requirement like sending email alert when key Vault secret is about to expire **by using** different approaches like alerts and **logic Apps**.

- By following this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-tutorial) Azure Event Grid to receive and respond to key vault notifications, created webhook in automation runbook as shown.
  [image]
- Then created Event grid as shown in below image by taking Topic Type: Key vault and select source as created key vault
  Endpoint Type: Webhook

[image]

- Then in key vault create secrets by mentioning expiry date and here if you want you can add tags.
  [image]
- Here as shown in below image you can create alert rule based on your requirement and [monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-overview) keyvault.
  [image]
  **Using Logic Apps:**
- One way is by using [logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/event-grid-logicapps) we can send email alert when key Vault secret is about to expire.
- Crated logic App then based on your requirement you can use Azure event grid/ Azure Key vault trigger for key Vault secret expire and then select send email action.
- As shown in below image by following the document taken Azure event grid connector here you need to select
  Resource Type:**Microsoft.KeyVault.vaults**
  Event Type Item - 1: **"Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNearExpiry"/"Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretExpired".**
  [image]
- Then select outlook 365 connector and from the choose send email action. As shown in below image in TO add the email address for whom you want to send secret expiry mail. Then select subject and in Body as shown below from dynamic content you can select Id, time ...etc.

[image]

- Here i have taken SecretNearExp as event type so whenever secret go to expire will get a alert notification to mentioned mail.
  [image]

Comment: If the email is hard coded in the logic app, that means you have to have a separate LA for each key vault you monitor, assuming you want a different person emailed upon expiry.

I ended up creating an azure function that subscribed to the Event Grid topic of any key vault, then used the managed identity of the func to call the key vault to get the tags.